# Value stored to NSString during its initialization is never read

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

In my iOS app I have following code:

```
case SASpeechSubCase03:
{
     SAActivity currentActivity = self.mediator.selectedActivity;

     NSString *sActivity = NSLocalizedString(@"activity", @"activity");
     NSString *sActivity2 = NSLocalizedString(@"another activity", @"another activity");
     if(currentActivity == SAActivityWalk)
     {
        sActivity = NSLocalizedString(@"walk", @"walk");
        sActivity2 = NSLocalizedString(@"walking", @"walking");
     }
     else
     {
        sActivity = NSLocalizedString(@"run", @"run");
        sActivity2 = NSLocalizedString(@"jogging", @"jogging");
     }

     return [NSString stringWithFormat:speech.text, sActivity, sActivity2];

     break;
}
```

When I run bots on it, it gave me following warning:

> Bot Issue: analyzerWarning. Dead store.
>   Issue: Value stored to 'sActivity' during its initialization is never read.
>   File: SAAnnouncementService.m.
>   Integration Number: 42.
>   Description: Value stored to 'sActivity' during its initialization is never read.
>
> Bot Issue: analyzerWarning. Dead store.
>   Issue: Value stored to 'sActivity2' during its initialization is never read.
>   File: SAAnnouncementService.m.
>   Integration Number: 42.
>   Description: Value stored to 'sActivity2' during its initialization is never read.

Can someone tell what the problem might be here?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Here is the explanation of Dead store http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_store

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you initialized the variables and then directly started the if-else blocks, without using, i.e. reading, the initial values.

When execution gets to the if-else blocks, it will definitely be assigned a new value, no matter what value it was before.

Comment: I was getting this error. Gave some thought after reading your answer and used the array by using the remove all objects method right after initialization before setting the values in if-else block. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Although now that I understand it more closely, I was setting the value in if-else and the value I'm setting during initialization is never used so if I just remove the `[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]` since then I'm fine

Answer (score 3):

With the following line :

```
 NSString *sActivity = NSLocalizedString(@"activity", @"activity");
 NSString *sActivity2 = NSLocalizedString(@"another activity", @"another activity");
```

You are assigning string values to the sActivity and sActivity2 objects.

Then, these two values are modified in either if or else statement.

But, as the static analyzer mentions, the initial values of these objects (@"activity" and @"another activity") were never read before the second assignment (in if / else statement).

To avoid this warning you can replace the two lines above, by :

```
 NSString *sActivity = nil;
 NSString *sActivity2 = nil;
```

Hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you get a warning, the compiler tells you "what you are doing here looks like nonsense, and is most likely not what you want".

Look at these two statements:

```
 NSString *sActivity = NSLocalizedString(@"activity", @"activity");
 NSString *sActivity2 = NSLocalizedString(@"another activity", @"another activity");
```

Does the assignment serve any purpose? It doesn't look like it. So the compiler thinks "either the guy made a rather expensive call that is completely pointless, or he actually intended to use the result of NSLocalizedString but stored it in the wrong place. "

Since the compiler assumes that people don't do pointless things, it assumes that there is a bug in your code and tells you about it. It's the kind of thing where a human reviewing your code would stop and ask you what you were intending to do there.

Answer (score 0):

In your codes, `sActivity` would be set to either walk or run within IF/ELSE, so that the value set for `sActivity` this line

```
 NSString *sActivity = NSLocalizedString(@"activity", @"activity");
```

would never be read. It might not cause error but analyzer reminded you about this superfluous initialization. Try `NSString *sActivity=nil;`, see if the warning could be turned down.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using sActivity in if-else blocks, you are simply assigning it values based on decision, So either take it nil string  like

> sActivity = nil;

or like

> NSString *sActivity;

to remove waring .